# Django is not filtering many-to-many results in template

Tags: django

I have an application where people can vote for multiple artists. On the results page I want to filter on country. In other words: I only wan't to show votes that are cast from a certain country. The count of votes works, but in the template still all the emails of the voters are shown and not only from the country in the filter.

My model:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField('Artist name', max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 


class Vote(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    country = CountryField(default="US")
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, related_name='selectedartists')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

The part of the view where the filtering is done:

```
results = Artist.objects.filter(selectedartists__isnull=False)

if countryquery == '' or countryquery == 'all':
            countryquery = 'all'
            results = results.annotate(total=Count('selectedartists', distinct=True))

        else:
            results = results.filter(selectedartists__country=countryquery)
            results = results.annotate(total=Count('selectedartists', filter=Q(selectedartists__country=countryquery), distinct=True))
```

and this is my template

```
{% if results %}
    {% for artist in results %}
        {{artist.name}} Votes:{ artist.total }}
        Voters: {{artist.selectedartists.all|join:', '}}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <div class="noresults">No results</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, I believe the best approach is to simplify this:

```
{% if results %}
{% for artist in results %}
    {{artist.name}} Votes:{ artist.total }}
    Voters: {% for voter in artist.selectedartists.all %} 
             {{ voter }},{% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <div class="noresults">No results</div>
{% endif %}
```